# Article and Tags relationship in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build an Article-Tags relationship model in ASP.NET MVC. there are Articles, which can have have multiple tags (eg: funny, fools, serious etc) describing the type of the article. I am thinking of two approaches to make this relationship:
1. Making a many-to-many relationship between Article and Tags.

```
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}
```

2. Making enum of all tag names and including a List of tags in Article.

   ```
   public enum Tag
   {
       Funny = 1,
       Fools = 2,
       Cute = 3,
       Food = 4,
   }
   ```

Can anyone suggest me the best approach between two approaches? or any other approach?

thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Best" is a little subjective, but with the many-many table design you'll find it easier to do queries.  If you use a list of tags and decide you want to find a specific type of article, you'll have to parse the tags field first.  Not impossible to do that, but definitely less convenient than having the extra table.

It's also easier to create new tags on the fly if you just have to add a record to a table rather than recompile your software.

Comment: thank you phillip for the suggestion. this was my first question at stackoverflow. thank u for the answer. stackoverflow is great.